# Thread with capability of stopping it in any duration of time

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

is there any kind of Runnable, Callable or Thread with capability of stopping it in any duration of time?

I wrote something like this

```
public class ThreadRunner {

private ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor;

ThreadRunner() {
    threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

public void startThread(String endPoint, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    Runnable task = () -> {
        // some code which saves images from URL (1230 images) and updates progress bar
    };

    threadPoolExecutor.execute(task);

}

public void stopThread() {
    threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
}
}
```

Thread runs correctly, images are being saved, progress bar being updated, but when I want to stop thread (or maybe even pause process of saving if possible) by calling ThreadRunner class's method - nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong - or most likely - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [The Java Tutorials: Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: Read the JavaDoc on `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` and it should become somewhat clearer: that call will cause the executor service to shut down which will _try_ to interrupt already running tasks but "any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate" (from the JavaDoc). It all depends on how your task reacts to interrupts. Assuming your task runs a loop you could check `Thread.isInterrupted()` in the loop body.

Comment: Is it possible that do..while loop (which is placed in Runnable) doesn't want to let thread being shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any kind of Runnable, Callable or Thread with capability of stopping it in any duration of time?

You can implement such a thing yourself, but there is no generic support available for it, unless you count the long-deprecated `Thread.stop()` methods.  Under no circumstances should you use those methods, but do read [their API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) for a discussion of why they are deprecated and what you can do instead.  You can find a longer-form version of the discussion [in Java's technical notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

The bottom line is that the computation you want to be able to stop needs to periodically check some shared variable or built-in condition to determine whether to do so.  You arrange for that variable to be set when you want the thread to stop, and if you need to block until it does stop then you `join()` it.  Under some circumstances, it can be helpful to `interrupt()` the thread to get it to check the variable (or being interrupted can itself serve as the termination condition).  The user-facing end of this can be wrapped up in a method.

In any case, an `ExecutorService` cannot give you a handle on this.  Requesting such a service to shut down will prevent it from dispatching any more tasks, but there is no safe, general-purpose mechanism by which it could force a premature shutdown of tasks that are already running.

Answer (score 0):

Once started, a thread will run until `Runnable.run()` exits. Due to several issues you should never use `Thread.stop()` or `Thread.interrupt()`.

Instead, you will have to implement your own logic for exit/pause. A few suggestions:

- For stopping the thread, you can make a boolean variable `shouldExit`. In your thread, check this variable every now and then, and just do "return" or break the for/while loop when it becomes `true`. Setting this variable from another thread should now make the downloader exit. If necessary, you should surround access to this variable with `synchronized` block as to prevent any race conditions.
- For pausing the thread, you can use a similar approach. When you set a certain variable to true (e.g. `isPaused`), make the thread react by going into an `Object.sleep()`. This way, it won't consume any CPU during sleep. You can then use `Object.notify()` from another thread to "kick" the sleeping thread out ouf sleep. You will need a `synchronized` block here, too.